# How to set ON CONFLICT?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy ORM and SQLite how make a table definition, like raw `UNIQUE(fld) ON CONFLICT REPLACE`?

This should be analogy of raw query, like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (fld TEXT UNIQUE, UNIQUE(fld) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

There is `INSERT…ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [for MySQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert), and it is not the definition.

Comment: Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/luJMpFwq48I

Comment: There is talk that such creating can only by the raw query `engine.execute("CREATE TABLE ....")` with `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`. (Also there is way for use this by `insert`, that need testing.)  So, a tables creates via a literal strings, and below in script will the table definitions in the classes for ORM. But then there will be confusion and duplication of this literal and class definitions. Another difficulty is that my tables have many fields. I use SqlAlchemy ORM just not to mass duplicate field names as quoted literals.

Comment: Is it possible to change the table creation query by adding `ON CONFLICT` in some instance before sending `Base.metadata.create_all()`? (I use the `Base = declarative_base()` to create tables.)

Answer (score 3):

`ON CONFLICT` in SQLite constraints has been [supported since SQLAlchemy 1.3](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#on-conflict-support-for-constraints).

A constraint can be applied inline in a column description

```py
tbl1 = sa.Table(
    't1',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column(
        'name', sa.String, unique=True, sqlite_on_conflict_unique='REPLACE'
    ),
    sa.Column('colour', sa.String),
)
```

generating this DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        colour VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (name) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

Or as a separate constraint:

```py
tbl2 = sa.Table(
    't2',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String),
    sa.Column('colour', sa.String),
    sa.Column('size', sa.Integer),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('name', 'colour', sqlite_on_conflict='IGNORE')
)
```

generating

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2 (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        colour VARCHAR, 
        size INTEGER, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (name, colour) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
)
```